# How to change the width of list box in html?

Tags: html

How to change the width of list box

```
<select id ="tagsList" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" width="100" size="18" multiple="multiple">
```

I try `width="100"` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the width using inline css like this:

```
<select style="width: 100px;"></select>
```

In with the rest of your attributes.

There are other ways to specify the width of an element, and most revolve around CSS. [Here's a link](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/#css) to Google's CSS education video that should get you more than primed and ready to go.

Comment: link no longer active because The University Consortium is no longer actively maintained.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use CSS:

```
<select id="tagsList" style="width:100px;">
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use CSS's width property. Add `style="width: 100px;"`

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id ="tagsList" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width:100;" size="18" multiple="multiple">
```

this code almost your i just added that style that is enough